# anti hotlink with fake user agent

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example1.org/XXXX/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example2.org/XXXX/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|palmos|webos|playstation) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(rar|zip|mp4|mkv|avi|mp3)$ http://example.org/nohotlink.html [R,NC,L]
```

I thought that it was perfect, but some sites and mobile apps still can steal my files, so i thought to make a php page with a fake user agent, for example PLAYSTATION

so inside .htaccess I put

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(playstation) [NC]
```

and inside php I put

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (PLAYSTATION 3; 3.55)');
```

will this work and stop that sites/apps from stealing my files and force them to use my php page?
and can I set a fake user agent?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(fakeuseragent) [NC] inside .htaccess
ini_set('user_agent', 'Fake/1.0 (fakeuseragent; 1.11)'); inside php
```

Comment: I can scrap **any** page I like with cURL.

Comment: yes, if you know the useragent, or even without knowing it?

Comment: Using a cURL, I can mimic any user-agent